# Let $A$, $B$ be normal subgroups and $A\cap B=\{e\}$. Prove that $ab=ba$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A$, $B$ be normal subgroups and $A\cap B=\{e\}$. Prove that $ab=ba$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$.

As soon as $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups, one can get that $aB=Ba$ and $bA=Ab$ for all $a\in A$, $b\in B$. Hence, there are such $a'\in A$ and $b'\in B$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $ab=b'a$ and $ba=a'b$, so we need to proof that $a=a'$ and $b=b'$. How do I use second condition that subgroups intersection is $\{e\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $[a,b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

We know that $aba^{-1} \in B$, so $[a,b] = (aba^{-1})b^{-1} \in B$.

Also, $ba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$, so $[a,b] = a(ba^{-1}b^{-1}) \in A$.

This means that $[a,b] \in A$ and $[a,b] \in B$, so $[a,b] \in A \cap B = \{e\}$, so $[a,b] = e$, and $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$, and $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 2):

From normality $aba^{-1} \in B$, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ also lives in $B$ as it is a subgroup.  Likewise $ba^{-1}b^{-1} \in A$ by normality, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ lives in $A$.  But the only thing living in both $A$ and $B$ is $e$, so $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=e$ and $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ab = ba$ iff $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$.

Since $B$ is normal, $aba^{-1} \in B$, which implies that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in B$.

Similarly, since $A$ is normal, $ba^{-1}b^{-1}\in A$, which implies that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in A$.

Conclusion?